# zoom problem in react-leaflet or setting current zoom to zoom attribute in MapContainer component

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I want show markers on map when user zoomin when zoom > 10 , I did this in my personal project and I was succseed but when implement in code below facing to a problem that I explained :
my zoom attribute in MapContainer in reactleaflet get current zoom by zoomend eventhandler in MyMapComponent but suddenly zoom set to 6  and dont let the user to zoom more than 6, I dont know where is the problem I ckecked all states but didnt find problem

```
const Map = ({ reload, showMarker, setShowMarker, showModal, setShowModal, selectedFolder, filteredData, setFilteredData, search, pointer, pageFeatures, setShowInfo, setSideBarWidth, setButtonPosition, setShowSidebar }) => {
    const allOrgansInfo = DC.app.getValue('allInfos')
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState(null)
    const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0)
    const [foundCenters, setFoundCenters] = useState([])
    const [userSelectedCenter, setUserSelectedCenter] = useState([])
    const [selectedCenter, setSelectedCenter] = useState(null)
    /*const [searchBar, setSearchBar] = useState(false)*/
    const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(8)


    useEffect(() => {
     
        console.log('zoomLevel in Map', zoomLevel)
    }, [zoomLevel])


    // console.log('zoom changed in child component', zoomLevel)
    //here





    const handleSelectCenter = (center) => {

        localStorage.setItem("lastSelectedLoc", center?.point || [35.6898, 51.3590])
        if (!(selectedCenter?.[0] && selectedCenter?.[1])) {
            if (selectedCenter?.[0]) {
                setSelectedCenter([selectedCenter[0], center])
            } else {
                setSelectedCenter([center, selectedCenter?.[1] ? selectedCenter?.[1] : null])
            }
        }
    }

    const [position, setPosition] = useState(() => {
        const lasLocation = localStorage.getItem("lastSelectedLoc") || null
        return lasLocation ? lasLocation.split(',') : [35.6898, 51.3590]
    })
    const [haveSearch, setHaveSearch] = useState(false)
    const [loadingSearch, setLoadingSearch] = useState(false)
    const onSearchArea = (map) => {
        setLoadingSearch(true)
        try {
            const bounds = map.getBounds()
            const area = convertBounds(bounds)

            setFoundCenters(
                (DC.server.response?.activeCenters || []).filter(q => inArea(q.point, area))
            )
        } catch {

        } finally {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setLoadingSearch(false)
                setHaveSearch(true)
            }, 500)
        }
    }

    const locationSet = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            setPosition([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
        });
    }



    // const locationSet = (latitude, longitude) => {
    //     setPosition([latitude, longitude])
    //     console.log(latitude, longitude)
    // }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     locationSet()
    // }, [])


    const [showReserveForm, setShowReserveForm] = useState(false)
    const clearCenter = () => {
        setShowReserveForm(false);
        handleSelectCenter(null)
    }
    const getDistanceText = (distance) => {
        const km = parseInt(distance / 1000);
        const m = parseInt(((distance / 1000) - (parseInt(distance / 1000))) * 1000)
        return `${km} کیلومتر و ${m} متر`
    }
    // const showSelectedOrganInfo = (userSelectedArea) => {
    //     // CLICK HERE

    //     let areaStats = allOrgansInfo.filter(q => q?.org == userSelectedArea)
    //     console.log(userSelectedArea)


    //     return areaStats
    // }

    const areaPolygonClickHandler = (e, item) => {
        // setUserSelectedCenter(showSelectedOrganInfo(item?.description?.medu_org_path))
        console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, 'item is set')

        locationSet(parseFloat(e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4)), parseFloat(e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4)))
        // console.log('marker clicked', item?.description?.medu_org_path, showSelectedOrganInfo(item?.description?.medu_org_path))
    }

    // console.log(isPointInsidePolygon([37.3626, 52.3786], polygonCoordinates))

    const topLeft = [41.7767, 36.9006]; // Bottom-left corner (latitude, longitude)
    const bottomRight = [21.0645, 73.3172]; // Top-right corner (latitude, longitude);
    const bounds = [topLeft, bottomRight];



    return (
        <div className="brz-fullwidth w3-border w3-border-blue">

            {showModal && <ImagesModal {...{ setShowModal }} />}
            <div style={{ zIndex: 0, position: 'relative' }}>
                {/*  <RForm {...generateProvincePositionForm({ setPosition })} />*/}

                <MapContainer center={position} maxBounds={bounds} maxBoundsViscosity={1.0} zoom={zoomLevel}
            
                >
                    <TileLayer


                        attribution='OpenStreetMap'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
                    <MyMap

                        {...{
                            reload, showMarker, setShowMarker, selectedFolder, filteredData, setFilteredData, search, pointer, setShowSidebar, setButtonPosition, setShowInfo, setSideBarWidth,
                            position, locationSet, foundCenters, handleSelectCenter,
                            loadingSearch, haveSearch,
                            setHaveSearch, onSearchArea, selectedCenter, setDistance
                        }}

                    />

                    <MyMapEvent
                        // onChangeZoom={onChangeZoom} 
                        zoom={zoomLevel} setZoomLevel={setZoomLevel}
                    />

                    {/* window.Map_Iran_Province_Relation_Polygon.map((item, index) => (
                        <Polygon key={index}
                            eventHandlers={{ click: (e) => areaPolygonClickHandler(e, item) }}
                            pathOptions={{ color: getColorOfPolygon(item.description) }}
                            posrate    <div>adsf</div>
                                   <div>adsf</div>
                                   <div>adsf</div>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </Popup>


                        </Polygon>
                    )) */}

                </MapContainer>


                {userSelectedCenter?.length > 0 &&
                    <Modal
                        style={{ zIndex: 1002 }}
                        show={userSelectedCenter}
                        onClose={() => { setUserSelectedCenter([]) }}
                    >
                        <div className="brz-tsh-i w3-center w3-padding">

                            <h4>مشخصات پسرها:</h4>
                            {Object.keys(userSelectedCenter[1]?.stats).map(key => {
                                return <p>
                                    {microScale?.[key]} : {JSON.stringify(userSelectedCenter[1]?.stats?.[key])}
                                </p>
                            })}

                            <h4>مشخصات دخترها:</h4>

                            <h4>مشخصات پسرها/دخترها:</h4>

                        </div>
                    </Modal>}
                {!selectedCenter ? '' :
                    <BottomNavigation
                        loading={showReserveForm}
                        onClick={() => { setShowReserveForm(true) }}
                        onClose={clearCenter}
                        item={selectedCenter}
                        setSelectedCenter={setSelectedCenter}
                        setDetail={setDetail}
                        detail={detail}
                    />
                }
                {!selectedCenter || !showReserveForm ? '' :
                    <ReserveCenterModal
                        {...{ child, impl }}
                        center={selectedCenter}
                        onClose={clearCenter} />
                }

            </div>
            {selectedCenter?.[0] && selectedCenter?.[1] ?
                <div className="brz-margin-t-l brz-margin-b-l" style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                    <div className="w3-button w3-blue  w3-round-large brz-flex brz-margin-auto brz-jcc" style={{ width: '40%' }}>
                        فاصله ی این دو مدرسه {getDistanceText(distance)}  است
                        </div>
                </div> : ''}
            {detail ?
                <div className='brz-margin-t-l' id='school-details'>
                    <div className="brz-margin-t-l brz-margin-b-l" style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                        <div className="w3-button w3-red  w3-round-large brz-flex brz-margin-auto brz-jcc" style={{ width: '40%' }} onClick={() => setDetail(null)}>
                            بستن اطلاعات
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <SchoolDetail item={detail} />
                </div>
                : ''}
        </div >
    )
}




const MyMapEvent = ({ onChangeZoom ,setZoomLevel , zoom}) => {
  const [searchBar, setSearchBar] = useState(false);
  const map = useMap()

  useMapEvent({
    zoomend: () => {
      const newZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
      setZoomLevel(newZoomLevel)
      console.log('current =', newZoomLevel)

      if (newZoomLevel >= 10) {
      setSearchBar(true)
      }
    }
  })
  
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('currentzoom in MyMapComponent',zoom)
},[zoom])


  return (
    <>
      { searchBar && <SearchBar><span className="material-icons-outlined">close</span></SearchBar>}

    </>
  )

}
```